# How to find the local IP address that will be used for communication with a remote IP

Tags: networking, network-programming

Given that the local machine has multiple interfaces and I connect to a remote machine, the OS will choose the interface through which the remote IP address is reachable. If my client doesn't explicitly bind to a specific IP and if the remote machine is reachable via more than one interface, is there a way to detect which local IP address will be used for the communication or is it purely random?

Comment: If you can get the routing-table, you might get hints about it, but before the connection is made there's no way of being sure. If the source of the OS is available you will be able to make more a precise guess though.

Answer (score 1):

In Linux at least, it needs to have the route specified in the routing table, it is not random.